# Styling Java with HTML/CSS

Tags: java, html, css, intellij-idea

So im fairly new to Java, anyway i have a implemented a simple Java program on IntelliJ which runs in the IntelliJ terminal, it basically ask the user to input some details and then records them along with the current time.
I now want to style it out using HTML/CSS to convert it into a webpage, where the user would enter the details into input boxes etc.
Im not sure how to approach this, what would be my best shot?

Also the user input is also being stored in a variable at the moment, would i have to use a database instead for a webpage?
Thanks.

Comment: IntelliJ can help with HTML and CSS editing, but there's no magic about knowing how to hook up a web page with a server back end.

Comment: As im fairly new to Java, would it work if created a HTML form as the front end and the Java as the backend? If so, where would i need to store the input data? Are variables fine? Secondly, how would i link the form to the Java backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would recommend you to read first about what is Model-View-Controller paradigm in web page architecture, then you can probably better reply to yourself in terms of what you need for your webpage in order to do what you want.

I will grasp some about the things that you need:

- You will need a database to store your user input details along with  with the current time. (MySQL for example)
- After that you need to define which type of data you need to save, you will have to make models in java for parsing those details from java to the db and vice versa.
- Then you will need to create some services (You can learn about repositories before services if you need, which you probably would) to support those connections with the database in which you will retrieve data from DB.
- A way to control how those services to serve your webpage is having a controller for processing the HTTP requests.
- Last but not least, the controller will "glue" your jsp views with the data from services to be shown in your browser.

There will be many other ways, at least this is the way I know. I use Spring framework for building the MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do full stack page with java backend and html & css for the front-end.
Do a webservice with spring boot this generate a restful API to communicate with your web page using HTTP methods ( Get, Post, Put and delete )  and use AngularJS for example to parse the webservice created.

check out this  : [example](http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, you'll need a web server to spit out HTML. I mean, there's lots of ways you could do it, but far and away the most popular is a web server.

There are lots of options for you. As an Eclipse fanboy myself, I can't say specifically, but a cursory google search yields [this Tomcat plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8266-tomcat-runner-plugin-for-intellij) which should allow you to run a web server via IntelliJ. There are probably dozens of other plugins for differnt web servers you could use.

What you put into that server is up to you - it could be a simple html document populated by parameters, a REST endpoint, a JSP, who knows what. That's beyond the scope of the question - the first step is getting your web server up and running and then deciding the framework to use.